# Kafka Consumer - continue calling poll() while paused?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I read the docs on using the pause and resume methods for a kafka consumer, and they seem easy enough to implement.  However, do I need another thread to continue calling the poll() method while paused to meet the heartbeat requirements and not trigger a rebalance?

My consumer is running SQL scripts after polling the topic and depending the messages returned, the scripts may take longer than the current session.timeout.ms interval (we have increased this value, but the length of time for the scripts to run can vary quiet a bit and regardless of the interval we will exceed it at times).  I also want to avoid a rebalance as safe ordering and data integrity are more important than throughput and error detention.

Comment: why not reduce the batch size of consumer ? so that it doesn't take long time

Comment: We tested with varying batch sizes and with the amount of processing we need to do for a single message we still run the risk of timing out (think car dealerships with hundreds of vehicles and associated coverages)

Answer (score 1):

yes, you need to continue calling `poll()` on the consumer, even if you pause all partitions, or it will be kicked out of any consumer group its a member of and its assigned partitions will transfer to another consumer. as to which thread ends up calling poll - that doesnt matter (so long as only a single thread interacts with the consumer at a time)

quoting from [kip-62](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-62%3A+Allow+consumer+to+send+heartbeats+from+a+background+thread):

> max.poll.interval.ms. This config sets the maximum delay between client calls to poll(). When the timeout expires, the consumer will stop sending heartbeats and send an explicit LeaveGroup request.